# Order of growth of partial sums of powers of a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, asymptotics

Suppose that $f[x]$ is an infinite sequence taking values in $[0, 1]$ (i.e. it is bounded and non-negative). We want to look at the sequence of partial sums:

$F[x] = \sum_{n=1}^x f[n]$

Let's also define $F_p[x]$ as the sequence of partial sums of the $p$'th powers of the sequence:

$F_p[x] = \sum_{n=1}^x f[n]^p$

Suppose we know the growth rate of $F[x]$ in terms of two functions:

$F[x] = g(x) + O(h(x))$

Can we thus extrapolate to get the growth rate of $F_p[x]$?

Comment: Your notation is a bit mysterious since $x$ is the upper limit of what appears to be a discrete sum, but also a function variable.

Comment: Oops, cleaned up the notation.

Comment: Are you describing a sequence of functions?  In this case, how to you distinguish between the sequence index and the dependent variable of the function.  If you are describing a sequence of functions, maybe $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}.$

Comment: No, I'm not describing a sequence of functions, just a simple partial sum of a single sequence, and a set of related functions that are simple partial sums of the powers of that sequence. I'm unfamiliar with the proper notation, but I thought what I had was unambiguous.

Comment: The basic view was I wanted $F_p[x]$ to be the sequence of partial $p$-norms of the first $x$ terms of $f[n]$, although I didn't raise to the power of $1/p$ at the end to make it simple.

Comment: Ok.  That makes more sense.